# Coverage report of nosetests in case of child process

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage, nosetests, coverage.py

I am using nosetests for unit testing of some python script. The script in question creates a child process.
I am executing the script using the command :
*nosetests -s -v 'python script.py' --with-coverage*

I have installed **nose-cov**. Its version is **1.6**.

The coverage report that I am getting doesn't contain the coverage of the code executed by the child.

**IS THERE ANY WAY OF GETTING THE COVERAGE OF THE CHILD PROCESS??**

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Nose is using outstanding [coverage](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/%20coverage) package under covers do the job. Assuming that you launch of your child process using subprocess, within your test you can temporarily [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/%20mock) or monkey patch the launch your child as:

```
subprocess.call(['coverage', 'run', 'my_child_program.py', '-p'])
```

With `-p` option to combine reports. You may need other options to make sure that your nose options point to the same `.coverage` report file as your subprocess call.